# Intermittent Timeout Exception during Workflow

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

Intermittently during workflow I am seeing the following exception:

```
Component: WorkflowEventsException
Errorcode: 0
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation, CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteReader(StoredProcedureInvocation storedProcedureInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Workflow.TridionActivityDefinitionDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id, StoredProcedureInvocation spInvocation)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.IdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IIdentifiableObjectDataMapper.Read(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetDataObject(TcmUri id)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags flags, Boolean forceReload)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Reload()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.get_Description()
   at XXX.EventSystem.WorkflowEvents.SaveAndStartActivityInstanceWorkflowEvent(ActivityInstance subject) in WorkflowEvents.cs:line 89
```

Line 89 is quite trivial, all it is doing is getting the description (as the exception indicates) of the ActivityDefinition

```
switch (subject.ActivityDefinition.Description)
{
    //cases
}
```

I can increase the timeout of Workflow tasks, but this seems like a very simple action that is causing the timeout.

Comment: *(1)* Is this items in a workflow bundle? *(2)* How many items are you pushing through workflow - i.e. does this ever happen when you've only a few items being processed? *(3)* Do you have workflow auditing switched on? *(4)* Do you have any event system code (or anything going at the database instance) that could be impacting your tests?

Comment: Not in a Workflow bundle, just a single Component
Very little in Workflow, less than 10 items
How do I switch on WF auditing? :)
There is event code

Comment: http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-2264235C-36D3-4A42-8545-F5B79868ADCB

This will save a snapshot of each component in the workflow (Bundle) as each activity is complete - this can bloat the relevant database table considerably and there's no OOTB framework for tidying it up so use with caution and proper monitoring ;)

Regards the timeout then - you'd assume it's something with the event code - perhaps there's some timing issue with the event of saving and starting the activity instance and interrogating the Activity Definition (have you confirmed it exists)?